# CakePHP routing syntax

Tags: cakephp, syntax, routes

How do I do a simple route in [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP)?

I need that each and every URL will be routed by swapping the action and the controller.
I just couldn't understand the placeholders syntax.

Example:

```
/files/read/3
```

to

```
/read/files/3
```

### -- supplemental --

In my application I use aliases for the controllers.
and I want to route every url that have a certain keyword, as an action, to a certain controller.
I also want to provide the original controller name as a parameter.
Here is a 1:1 example:
There are to alises: `fruits` and `streets`.
The keyword that I want to catch in the action is `find`.
The new controller name is `finder`.
The following calls match my condition:
`/fruits/find/apple/red` and `/streets/find/longer`
The router should catch these urls and convert them, to:
`/finder/fruits/apple/red`(or supply the parameters in other way, I don't mind) and `/finder/streets/longer`

How should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the line of code that you need to put in `/app/config/routes.php`:

`Router::connect('/:action/:controller/*', array('controller' => ':controller', 'action' => ':action'));`

**Know more:** As you can see from the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration), there are some 'reserved' patterns for routing configuration. An example would be what I used in the line above: `:action` and `:controller`. These patterns allow you to tweak routes extensively.

**Beware**: changing the order of controller and actions in urls might have unintended consequences in the functionality of other CakePHP features. I haven't tested thoroughly, but this is just a general warning.

**Beware**: Also, I noticed that you put in your example: `/files/read/3`. Maybe this was just some dummy example, but if you indeed plan to have an MVC named as 'file', be advised that it will conflict will CakePHP core classes (e.g. `File` model will conflict with `File` class).

Anyway, hope this answer helps you well. And I really like how the change of controller and action names make the url more readable. :D

Comment: I thank you a lot @YOMorales , at least half of it is now clear to me. however, i still don't understand something, i will add it to the question itself.

Comment: Hi: I will try to answer your followup later, but I'm very busy now. :)